# How does only shows a white referencial on dash application?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, line-plot

I'm trying to deploy some app in dash but, although the dropdowns appears correcty, the plots are not getting called.

I already tried a lot of different things, but it always goes to a white referencial...

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.colors import n_colors
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


df = pd.read_csv('movies.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")


df.columns = df.columns.str.capitalize()
    
###################### APP ############################

app = dash.Dash(__name__)


app.layout = html.Div([
    
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id = 'our_graph')
    ],className = 'nine columns'),

    html.Div([

        html.Br(),
        html.Label(['Choose Country / Genre / Company:'],style={'font-weight': 'bold', "text-align": "center"}),
        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'country_drop',
            options = [{'label':country, 'value':country} for country in df['Country'].unique()],
            value = 'USA',
            multi = False,
            disabled=False,
            clearable=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder='Choose Country...',
            className='form-dropdown',
            style={'width':"90%"},
            persistence='string',
            persistence_type='memory'),

        dcc.Dropdown(id= 'genre_drop',
            options = [{'label': genre, 'value' : genre} for genre in df['Genre'].unique()],
            value = 'Drama',
            multi = False,
            disabled=False,
            clearable=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder='Choose Genre..',
            className='form-dropdown',
            style={'width':"90%"},
            persistence='string',
            persistence_type='memory'),

        dcc.Dropdown(id = 'company_drop',
            options = [{'label':company, 'value':company} for company in df['Company'].unique()],
            value = 'Paramount Pictures',
            multi = False,
            disabled=False,
            clearable=True,
            searchable=True,
            placeholder='Choose Company..',
            className='form-dropdown',
            style={'width':"90%"},
            persistence='string',
            persistence_type='memory'),

        ],className='three columns')

])


####################Callbacks#######################

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('our_graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("company_drop", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("country_drop", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("genre_drop", "value")
     ]
)
def plots(country, genre,company):
    new_df = df.loc[(df['Country'] == country) & (df['Genre'] == genre) & (df['Company'] == company)]
    revenue_df = new_df.groupby(by = ['Year'])['Gross','Budget'].sum()
    fig = px.line(revenue_df, x=revenue_df.index, y=revenue_df.columns, title = 'Which Country has the highest revenue by category?',
                labels=dict(x="Year", y= 'Amount of $ in billions'))
    return fig


#Run App
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app.run_server(debug=False)`
```

If someone can help me out...i'm a begginer but although it might be simples i'm already looking for the solution into 2 days...

Comment: If you have the toy data, I can verify it in my environment, but can you provide the data?

Comment: @r-beginners   https://www.kaggle.com/danielgrijalvas/movies

Comment: @r-beginners sorry to bother you again, but did u find something ? I'm really desperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the data is not displayed is that the order of the drop-down and the order in which it is received by the graph function are different, so the acquired data does not exist, resulting in an error.

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('our_graph', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Input("company_drop", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("country_drop", "value"),
     dash.dependencies.Input("genre_drop", "value"))

def plots(company, country, genre):
    new_df = df[(df['Country'] == country) & (df['Genre'] == genre) & (df['Company'] == company)]
    revenue_df = new_df.groupby(by = ['Year'])[['Gross','Budget']].sum()
    revenue_df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    fig = px.line(revenue_df,
                  x='Year',
                  y=['Gross', 'Budget'],
                  title='Which Country has the highest revenue by category?',
                 ) 
    
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text='YEAR')
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text='Amount of $ in billions')
    return fig
```

[image]